# Gulp Browsersync and http-proxy-middleware in offline mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browser-sync, node-http-proxy

Does Browsersync with [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) work offline if I am proxying to a localhost server?

I have an angular app deployed at `localhost:3000` making requests for an api-server deployed at `localhost:8080`. The http requests to the api-server are proxied by Browsersync `http-proxy-middleware`. Everything works fine if I have internet connection but, if I go offline, I get the following error on gulp console:

```
[HPM] Proxy error: ENOENT localhost:8080/data/pet
```

And on browser console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `500 (Internal Server Error)`
```

I know the error is not on the server because I can still reach `localhost:8080/data/pet` with the browser.

Since the api-server is deployed locally, it seems odd that I need an internet connection to proxy the http requests.

The angular application, with all its configuration, was generated with the [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular)

This is my gulp server configuration:

```js
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var browserSyncSpa = require('browser-sync-spa');

var util = require('util');

var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

function browserSyncInit(baseDir, browser) {
  browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser;

  var routes = null;
  if (baseDir === conf.paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(conf.paths.src) !== -1)) {
    routes = {
      '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
    };
  }

  var server = {
    baseDir: baseDir,
    routes: routes
  };


  server.middleware = proxyMiddleware('/data',
    {
      target: 'http://localhost:8080'
    });

  browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    startPath: '/',
    server: server,
    browser: browser,
    online: false
  });
}

browserSync.use(browserSyncSpa({
  selector: '[ng-app]'// Only needed for angular apps
}));

gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
});
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "petStore",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~2.3.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.6.0",
    "del": "~1.2.0",
    "lodash": "~3.9.3",
    "gulp-csso": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~2.0.2",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.0.4",
    "gulp-jshint": "~1.11.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-size": "~1.2.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-useref": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.5",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.3",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "~5.0.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-minify-html": "~1.0.3",
    "gulp-inject": "~1.3.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.5.2",
    "gulp-less": "~3.0.3",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.8.0",
    "merge-stream": "~0.1.7",
    "jshint-stylish": "~2.0.0",
    "wiredep": "~2.2.2",
    "karma": "~0.12.36",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-angular-filesort": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.2",
    "concat-stream": "~1.5.0",
    "require-dir": "~0.3.0",
    "browser-sync": "~2.7.12",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.2.0",
    "chalk": "~1.0.0",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "wrench": "~1.5.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

And this is the http call:

```
  $http.get("/data/pet").then(function (result) {
        vm.petName = result.data.name;
      });
```

And bower.json

```
{
  "name": "petStore",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.0",
    "malarkey": "yuanqing/malarkey#~1.3.0",
    "toastr": "~2.1.1",
    "moment": "~2.10.3",
    "animate.css": "~3.3.0",
    "angular": "~1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Just did some tests and I can confirm this issue.
Ran the library tests with: "npm test".
It will setup actual servers to run some of the tests.

When online, all tests succeed.
But when running the tests offline, it will produce the same error message.

The actual proxy functionality is provided by [node-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy).

This issue has been reported at:
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/835

I'm also curious why http-proxy can't be used offline.

(disclaimer: I'm the author of http-proxy-middleware.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like core browsersync doesn't require an internet connection. Some features do.

The following setting lets you switch browsersync to offline mode:  https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-online

I set this property in the server.js file and my app works off line:

`browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    startPath: '/',
    server: server,
    browser: browser,
    online: false
  });`