# Node http-proxy-middleware not working with local servers as targert

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I have a node server and I am proxying my api requests using `http-proxy-middleware`, similar to what happens in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31405955/916450). When I proxy to real production server everything works just fine, but when I point the proxy to a local server it just doesn't work.

This is my code:

`app.use('/_api', proxy({target: 'http://localhost:9000', changeOrigin: true}));`

The server on:

`http://localhost:9000/hello` is working (I can access it from my browser), but, when I try to access it from my own server, like this:

`http://localhost:3000/_api/hello`

I am getting:

> Cannot GET /_api/hello

If I replace localhost:9000 with real server, everything works...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your proxied request is trying to access the local server using the original request path.

Eg, when you request

`http://localhost:3000/_api/hello`

Your proxy is trying to access

`http://localhost:9000/_api/hello`

The `_api/hello` path does not exist on your `localhost:9000`, which is shown by the `Cannot GET /_api/hello` error.

You need to rewrite your proxied request paths to remove the `_api` part:

```
app.use('/_api', proxy({
    target: 'http://localhost:9000', 
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/_api' : '/'
    }
}));
```

Comment: wouldn't the prependPath parameter will do this?

Comment: @duncanhall can you help me on this , im trying to proxying my request from local to qa or prd , its not even recognizing the path which ever i have given ,  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639757/http-proxy-middleware-the-path-is-not-recognising)