# setupProxy.js path are not recognizing in reactjs application using http proxy middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am implementing http proxy middleware in my react app , my setupProxy.js path's are not recognising . Below is my code please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

App component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  test = () => {
// I dont have any thing which is running in "/api"  
// Simply called fetch with "/api" because setupPorxy.js  is looking my request or not 
    fetch("/api")
      .then(res => {
        alert('test pri')
        console.log('res', res)
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.test}>Test</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

setupProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

\\ I dont have any thing running on localhost 5000 , want to check the request is modified or not 

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:5000', changeOrigin: true }));
}
```

output

```
But ended with 404 not found in browser console like http://localhost:3000/api (404 not found)
```

[image]

When i start the application there were logs shown like below but not replacing the target
[image]

Comment: @chimurai   can you help me what i m doing wrong , have been stick with this issue aroung a day not sure whats wrong I am doing ,

Comment: did you create an express app, i mean in your setupProxy file, what is `app` ?

Comment: @Mu-Majid i did not create express() , because I have an rest api backend thats why .

Comment: Did you check this out? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: @JulianKleine yes checked copied ```setupProxy.js```  code from under this section Configuring the Proxy Manually from tht link only

Comment: @JulianKleine i did not add ```proxy``` variable in to package.json file is it still required .

Comment: Yes, i think it is required, i did not do it myself though

Comment: @Julian Kleine Okay you meant to add proxy variable in package. Json file right

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: No it's not working though @Julian Kleine

Comment: Can you add a working example? If you set up a simple create react app, are you able to use the proxy feature successfully?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223985/discussion-between-sakthisureshanand-and-julian-kleine).